# webrtc4all in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, sip, webrtc

I am trying to implement calling to SIP server using WebRTC(http://sipml5.org/) which works fine on google chrome, however i need to run this on Internet Explorer.

Even demo page from sipml5 didnt't worked on IE.

I am following this link(https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/) which mentions it is possible to implement this using `'webrtc4all_windows_1_35_981(stable).sfx.exe'`

Even after installing above 'exe' nothing works. Also how to debug in IE similar to using chrome's Developer Tools.

Please find my below code sample which works perfectly on Google chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Web to SIP call demo</title>
    <script src="SIPml-api.js?svn=179" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        var sipStack;
        var eventsListener = function (e) {
            console.info('eventsListener ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: session event = ' + e.type);
            if (e.type == 'started') {
                login();
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = "Connected.";
            }
            else if (e.type == 'i_new_message') { // incoming new SIP MESSAGE (SMS-like)
                acceptMessage(e);
            }
            else if (e.type == 'i_new_call') { // incoming audio/video call
                acceptCall(e);
            }
            else if (e.type == 'connecting') {
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = "connecting.....";
            }
            else if (e.type == 'i_ao_request') {
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = "ringing...";
            }
            else if (e.type == 'connected') {
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = "connected";
            }
            else if (e.type == 'terminated') {
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = "terminated";
            }

        }

        function createSipStack() {
            var ext = extension.value;
            if (ext == null || ext == '')
            {
                alert('null');
                ext = '5555';
            }
            sipStack = new SIPml.Stack({
                realm: '--myip address--', // mandatory: domain name
                impi: ext, // mandatory: authorization name (IMS Private Identity)
                impu: 'sip:' + ext + '@' + realm, // mandatory: valid SIP Uri (IMS Public Identity)
                password: '--mypassword--', // optional
                display_name: 'extension' + ext, // optional
                //websocket_proxy_url: 'wss://sipml5.org:10062', // optional
                //outbound_proxy_url: 'udp://example.org:5060', // optional
                enable_rtcweb_breaker: true, // optional
                events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener }, // optional: '*' means all events
                sip_headers: [ // optional
                        { name: 'User-Agent', value: 'IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0' },
                        { name: 'Organization', value: 'Doubango Telecom' }
                ]
            }
            );
        }
        //Initialize SIPml
        var readyCallback = function (e) {
            createSipStack(); // see next section
        };
        var errorCallback = function (e) {
            console.error('Failed to initialize the engine: ' + e.message);
        }


        //Register / login
        var registerSession;
        var login = function () {
            registerSession = sipStack.newSession('register', {
                events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener } // optional: '*' means all events
            });
            registerSession.register();
        }




        function onClickCall() {
            callSession = sipStack.newSession('call-audio', {
                audio_remote: document.getElementById('audio-remote'),
                bandwidth: { audio: undefined, video: undefined },
                events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener }, // optional: '*' means all events
                sip_caps: [
                           { name: '+g.oma.sip-im' },
                           { name: '+sip.ice' },
                           { name: 'language', value: '\"en,fr\"' }
                ]
            });
            callSession.call('w2s_' + mobilenumber.value);
        }

        function onClickHangup() {
            if (callSession) {
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = 'Terminating the call...';
                callSession.hangup({ events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener } });
            }
        }

        function onClickConnect()
        {
            SIPml.init(readyCallback, errorCallback);
            sipStack.start();
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family:Tahoma;
            font-size:small;        
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="txtCallStatus" style="font-style: italic"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="5555" id="extension" />  
    <input type="button" value="Connect" onclick="return onClickConnect()" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="mobilenumber" id="mobilenumber" />
    <input type="button" value="Call" onclick="return onClickCall()" />
    <input type="button" value="Hangup" onclick="return onClickHangup()" />
    <audio id="audio-remote" autoplay="autoplay" />
    <audio id="ringtone" loop src="sounds/ringtone.wav" />
    <audio id="ringbacktone" loop src="sounds/ringbacktone.wav" />
    <audio id="dtmfTone" src="sounds/dtmf.wav" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using chrome frame for internet explorer .. http://www.google.com/chromeframe?prefersystemlevel=true .. it may support webrtc.

Comment: Right now WebRTC is in draft status and Internet Explorer typically does not offer support for a standard until it is closer to recommendation status. http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/

Comment: Yes chrome frame has yet to be tried, however my client wont accept for it. :(

Comment: The webrtc4all works only in Browser mode:IE9, I am now able to login and authenticate to my sip server. However now getting a CODEC NEGOTIATION ERROR when bridging the call to PSTN network. This issue gets resolved in other browsers after enabling RTCWeb Breaker.